# Datos duplicados al recorrer JSON (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un JSON en el que guardo una serie de errores. Los voy a exportar a un CSV, por lo que necesito los valores de todos los campos (los habrá que estén contenidos en el error y otros que no), por ellos lo he condicionado con IFs anidados.

```
   var errorList = '[{"propertyName":"customerData.nifCif","error":"wrong","detail":"","value":"72007817D"},`{"propertyName":"address","error":"wrong","detail":"","value":"direcciomndhdjj"}]';
   var objErrList = JSON.parse(errorList);

for(var j = 0; j < objErrList.length; j++) {
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "customerData.nifCif") {

        if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
                console.log("wrong nif");
        } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
                console.log("empty nif");
        }

    } else {
        console.log("dni correcto");
    }
  if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "productType") {

        if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
            console.log("wrong productType");
        } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
            console.log("empty productType");
        }

    } else {
        console.log("productType correcto");
    }

      if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "address") {

        if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
            console.log("wrong address");
        } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
            console.log("empty address");
        }

    } else {
        console.log("address correcto");
    }
}
```

**El problema es que me saca multiplicados los datos** (si ejecutais ese código podéis comprobarlo.
**Sólo** necesito que me saque **una** **línea**, en plan:

```
wrong nif, productType correcto, wrong address
```

Vamos que una vez que compruebe en todos los propertyName que existe "nif" por ejemplo, guarde su valor y no vuelva a comprobarlo más.
**¿Cuál es la solución para que no se repitan las comprobaciones de datos?**

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo veo yo esto debería ser así

```html
var errorList = '[{"propertyName":"customerData.nifCif","error":"wrong","detail":"","value":"72007817D"},`{"propertyName":"address","error":"wrong","detail":"","value":"direcciomndhdjj"}]';
   var objErrList = JSON.parse(errorList);

for(var j = 0; j < objErrList.length; j++) {
    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "customerData.nifCif") {

        if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
                console.log("wrong nif");
        } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
                console.log("empty nif");
        } else {
         console.log("dni correcto");
     }

    }
  if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "productType") {

        if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
            console.log("wrong productType");
        } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
            console.log("empty productType");
        } else {
         console.log("productType correcto");
     }

    } 

      if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "address") {

        if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
            console.log("wrong address");
        } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
            console.log("empty address");
        } else {
         console.log("address correcto");
 }
    }

}
```

Comment: No me sirve del todo, ya que el dato "productType", aunque no esté en el JSON de errores también me gustaría que sacase el valor de "correcto", pero gracias por tu respuesta ;)

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que buscas, pero me ha parecido que es esto:

```
var errorList = '[{"propertyName":"customerData.nifCif","error":"wrong","detail":"","value":"72007817D"},{"propertyName":"address","error":"wrong","detail":"","value":"direcciomndhdjj"}]';
    var objErrList = JSON.parse(errorList);

    for (var j = 0; j < objErrList.length; j++) {
        if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "customerData.nifCif") {

            if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
                console.log("wrong nif");
            } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
                console.log("empty nif");
            } else {
                console.log("dni correcto");
            }

        } else {
            console.log("dni correcto");
        }
        if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "productType") {

            if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
                console.log("wrong productType");
            } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
                console.log("empty productType");
            } else {
                console.log("productType correcto");
            }

        } else {
            console.log("productType correcto");
        }

        if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "address") {

            if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
                console.log("wrong address");
            } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
                console.log("empty address");
            } else {
                console.log("address correcto");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("address correcto");
        }

    }
```